# Laravel 4 - Upload file and SQL

Tags: file, upload, laravel, laravel-4

I am creating an app which needs to upload files, specifically videos and I am using laravel to do server-side php.

I have a form on my view

```
{{ Form::open(array('route' => 'testuploads.store', 'files' => true, 'enctype' => 'multipart/form-data')) }}
<ul>
    <li>
        {{ Form::label('title', 'Title:') }}
        {{ Form::text('title') }}
    </li>

    <li>
        {{ Form::label('body', 'Body:') }}
        {{ Form::textarea('body') }}
    </li>

    <li>
        {{ Form::token() }}
        {{ Form::label('file', 'File:') }}
        {{ Form::file('file') }}
    </li>

    <li>
        {{ Form::submit('Submit', array('class' => 'btn btn-info')) }}
    </li>
</ul>
{{ Form::close() }}
```

A controller

```
public function store()
{
    $input = Input::all();

    $file = Input::file('file');
    $pubpath = public_path();
    $destinationPath = $pubpath.'/uploads/'.str_random(8);
    $filename = $file->getClientOriginalName();
    $extension = $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
    // $path = $file->getRealPath();
    $size = $file->getSize();
    $mime = $file->getMimeType();
    $uploadSuccess = Input::file('file')->move($destinationPath, $filename);

    $validation = Validator::make($input, Testupload::$rules);

    if ($validation->passes())
    {
        $this->testupload->create($input);
        return Redirect::route('testuploads.index');
    }

    return Redirect::route('testuploads.create')
        ->withInput()
        ->withErrors($validation)
        ->with('message', 'There were validation errors.');
}
```

The error I get is:

```
Symfony \ Component \ HttpFoundation \ File \ Exception \ FileException
Unable to create the "/www/test/public/uploads/xTzlVlxb" directory
```

I have tried to change the permissions to the upload directory too, but that didn't worked. Any help appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Is `/www/test/public/uploads/` writable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to create the folder first with this method:

```
 File::makeDirectory($destinationPath,  $mode = 0777, $recursive = false);
```

And then move your file into that folder. Also i recommend to first check if the folder is created succesfully with:

```
 File::exists($destinationPath);
```

Comment: Hi MaHo, thanks for the quick reply. That didn't worked either, the error has changed to an 

ErrorException
mkdir(): Permission denied

Comment: I see your own answer, that you renamed your folder. Are you sure that the first folder 'uploads' had the correct permissions? Because it sounds a little bit odd that it works with a different name..

Comment: I did changed the permissions originally and checked if there are the correct ones but didn't worked, and yes its odd. Anyway, its working now.